# Is there any substantial difference in syntax of state definition in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native, memory-management

Is there any difference (other than syntax) in defining `state` in React component (see examples below, in a class and in a constructor)?

A difference in terms of JS memory allocation, memory management, JS performance, memory leaks, garbage collection, other issues?

I usually define `state` in a `constructor`. But reviewing code of other guys I saw they define state in a class scope.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    // this style vs. ...
    state = {
        color: 'red'
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // ... vs. this style
        this.state = {
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a syntax sugar, both will give you the same underlining object.

Comment: @Keith syntactic sugar is a piece of code under the hood  that performs some operation to make syntactic sugar possible. It may be less or more costly operation.

Comment: No it's exactly the same, syntax sugar is just that,.  The class scope declarations are not even standard yet.  So there won't be any performance gain.

Comment: ps.  did you also mean ->  `state = { color: 'red' }`   https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: @Keith Yep, sure. Syntax error

Comment: This is at stage 3, so some browsers might be implementing soon,.  So you could maybe resurrect this thread in the future.. :)   My gut feeling though, even when browsers have implemented natively I doubt there would be much if any performance difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing instance properties outside of the constructor is a proposed syntax for the next version of EcmaScript. It's part of an [official stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

According to this proposal, the following snippet:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Hello from constructor!");
        this.x = 1;
    }
}
```

Can be shortened to:

```
class MyClass {
    x = 1;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Hello from constructor!");
    }
}
```

Where the property `x` is declared and initialized with the same syntax as the property `state` in your example.

Comment: There's no such thing as ES7. It's currently called ES.Next.

Comment: @estus Removed the version number reference.

Answer (score 0):

it's also a kind of PREACT syntax...